# Windows 8.1 Storage Spaces Pool deletion

Tags: windows-8.1, software-raid, storage-spaces

I am trying to delete my RAID 0 storage pool and it seems that maybe the storage spaces utility doesn't recognize the pool being there. According to [these screenshots](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/4205-storage-spaces-delete-storage-space-storage-pool-windows-8-a.html) (and others I have found that are identical but on different sites) there should be an option to just delete the pool, but I only have the option to create a new pool.

[image: my storage spaces screen]

I am logged in as the administrator so I don't think that is an issue. My Samsung Magician recognizes and is able to run a performance test with no issues. My Disk Management sees the striped pool. And it shows up in just my regular file manager just fine.

I do see the option in Disk Management to format or delete the volume (on right-click), but I don't want to do that if it will somehow corrupt the drives. Is there somewhere else/something else I can do? I am familiar and somewhat comfortable with working the CMD if need be, I'm much more familiar with Linux CLI commands and I know they're not really the same at all.

Computer Info:

- mobo: MSI Z97 SLI Plus
- CPU: Core i7
- OS: Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit
- SSD: Samsung 850 Pro OS disk
- Samsung 850 EVOs in striped configuration through Storage Spaces

Other potentially important info:

- mobo BIOS version 1.9
- SATA driver: Asmedia 106x version 3.1.8.0000

Now that I type out all those specs, I have updated the SATA drivers in the past with the pool in place, but nothing has ever gone wrong in those updates and everything has worked flawlessly until I just now decided to repurpose one of the drives to be used in dual boot instead.

Comment: How did you make the pool in the first place?  Are you sure it's not just set as RAID0 (via Disk Manager) and never actually been added to a Storage Pool?  If you split or break a RAID0, you'll lose all data (there's no way to avoid it) so backup all data form the RAID0 before breaking it.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yes, I did use storage spaces which is why it is so weird to me. I've already dumped the contents onto my HDD as a backup, it was mostly just a scratch disk for Adobe stuff (GoPro footage). Anyways, if I format it inside disk management, or choose to delete volume, will that cause any issues with the drives themselves? I'm fine deleting the data.